# Increase deployVerticle Timeout

Tags: groovy, vert.x

Using Vert.x I have a verticle with a very slow startup because it depends on several slow http requests.

It is completely async, but I still receive the following error because the Timeout of deployVerticle.

`(TIMEOUT,-1) Timed out after waiting 30000(ms) for a reply. address: d5c134e0-53dc-4d4f-b854-1c40a7905914, repliedAddress: my.dummy.project`

I am deploying the verticle as

```
def name = "groovy:my.dummy.verticle"
def opts = new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(config());

vertx.deployVerticle(name, opts, { res ->
    if(res.failed()){
        log.error("Failed to deploy verticle " + name)
    }
    else {
        log.info("Deployed verticle " + name)
    }
})
```

How can I increase those 30000ms to something more suitable for me? I know that the requests will take more than a minute.

Comment: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#_asynchronous_verticle_start_and_stop

Comment: @tim_yates maybe I am missing something while skimming the documentation, but I see no reference about increasing Timeout time. (before today I thought there was no timeout, but then again, before today I had no verticle with a init that slow)

Comment: Don't you just use start(Future) in your verticle, and use the future to say when you're ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message you're seeing is not directly related to the deployment. The message is coming from the event bus that did not receive a response to the sent message within 30 seconds.

You can increase that timeout using the `DeliveryOptions` http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/DeliveryOptions.html